# MinGW gcc unrecognized command line option '-Wl'/'Wa'/'Wp'

Tags: gcc, mingw

In short, I have the most recent version of MinGW and I am attempting to pass options into the linker and the like.

For example, I wanted to change the stack size by:

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,[new size in bytes]
```

But it recognized neither -Wl nor --stack. And that applies for the other options too.

I'm able to compile my programs all well in good, it just seems as though I cannot use the various gcc options.

Is this an issue with MinGW, or am I overlooking something more?

Comment: `gcc free.c --Wl,--cref` works for me, dumping a lot of lines. You said *it didn't recognize*. What does it mean? How did you verify that?

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed in the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) about passing arguments to linker, that you cannot have a space before the number, so it should be:

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,[new size in bytes]
```

Commas are changed into spaces, but a real space makes the next option gcc option, not linker option.

Comment: I suppose that was an error in my question formatting, if anything. That still does not work however, as I still get the errors relating to the "unrecognized command line option" for both -Wl and --stack.